# Monte Carlo Selection phase maximum recursion exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, tic-tac-toe, montecarlo

I'm trying to implement monte carlo tree search for an ultimate tictactoe game (its like tictactoe but the board is larger) and am having trouble in the selection phase of the alogirthm. My search tree is made up of individual nodes which the first part of the algorithm is trying to select one of to expand. However, I keep on getting an error that the maximum recursion has been reached:

```
def select_node(node, board, state, identity):
    """ Traverses the tree until the end criterion are met.

    Args:
        node:       A tree node from which the search is traversing.
        board:      The game setup.
        state:      The state of the game.
        identity:   The player's identity, either 1 or 2.

    Returns:        A node from which the next stage of the search can proceed.

    """

    if len(node.child_nodes) == 0 and len(node.untried_actions) > 0:    # Node is root, choose it
        return node

    best_child = None
    if board.current_player(state) == identity:    # its our turn 
        best_child_utc = -inf
        for move in node.child_nodes:
            child_node = node.child_nodes[move]
            if child_node.visits == 0:
                best_child = child_node
                break
            child_UCB_score = (child_node.wins/child_node.visits) + 1.41 * sqrt(log(node.visits)/child_node.visits)
            if child_UCB_score > best_child_utc:
                best_child = child_node
                best_child_utc = child_UCB_score
    else:    # its the opponents turn
        best_child_utc = -inf
        for move in node.child_nodes:
            child_node = node.child_nodes[move]
            if child_node.visits == 0:
                best_child = child_node
                break
            child_UCB_score = 1 - ((child_node.wins/child_node.visits) + 1.41 * sqrt(log(node.visits)/child_node.visits))
            if child_UCB_score > best_child_utc:
                best_child = child_node
                best_child_utc = child_UCB_score


    if best_child is not None and len(best_child.child_nodes) > 0 and not board.is_ended(best_child.state):
        return select_node(best_child, board, best_child.state, identity)
    else:
        return best_child
```

Is there any way to maybe transform my algorithm from being recursive to using some sort of loop so it doesn't hit the recursion limit? This is being played on 9x9 board so the maximum levels of recursion it could theoretically hit is 81.

Comment: well if theoretically the max recursion depth is 81 but you still exceed the default system limit, that sounds like there is a bug in your code... may be you should start looking for this bug first thing...

Comment: You're right! I just added a global variable to track the recursion depth and it seems like its reaching 1000 then crashing... wonder what it could be!

Comment: Are you handling cycles? What does `traverse_nodes` do? I don't see any recursive calls to `select_node`

Comment: Oh sorry, that should be `select_node` as well. I will change the original question.

Comment: *This is being played on 9x9 board so the maximum levels of recursion it could theoretically hit is 81.* I don't understand this ... can you explain?

Comment: Well if there's 81 squares, and my recursion goes down one level each time, there would be a maximum depth of 81.